# R Returns Wrong Minimum Value

Tags: r, sqlite, min

I'm using a SQLite database with approximately 1.2 million records.  When I use SQLite,

```
select min(borrowerCreditScore) from acquisitions;
```

I get a minimum of 350.  I think that is correct.

When I use R

```
range(dbGetQuery(fnma, "SELECT borrowerCreditScore from acquisitions"))
```

I get

```
[1]   0 850
```

the minimum of 0 is not correct, but the max of 850 is correct.

I duplicated the error with describe and summary with the same result.  I also tried

```
dbGetQuery(fnma, "SELECT COUNT(borrowerCreditScore) from acquisitions where borrowerCreditScore < 300")
```

and got 0 records, which is correct.

Various queries in SQLite return what appear to be correct answers.

Comment: can it be different handling of NaN values? what does `range(dbGetQuery(fnma, "SELECT min(borrowerCreditScore) from acquisitions"))` returns?

Comment: Try to do `SELECT borrowerCreditScore from acquisitions order by borrowerCreditScore` in sql and see if there are NAs.  If there are then try `range(dbGetQuery(fnma, "SELECT borrowerCreditScore from acquisitions where borrowerCreditScore is not null"))`